# Spring Cloud how to exclude BootstrapConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

Is there a way to exclude a specific BootstrapConfiguration declared in a META-INF/spring.factories file with the org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration key?

I wasn't able to find any documentation about it, even though I see the org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration annotation has an exclude field, it is not clear to me exactly how it should be used.

Comment: That field isn't used anywhere. It doesn't look like there is a way to exclude a bootstrap configuration. Which one are you tyring to exclude?

Comment: I am trying to exclude the AppConfigurationBootstrapConfiguration class that is specified in the following spring.factories file: https://github.com/microsoft/spring-cloud-azure/blob/master/spring-cloud-azure-appconfiguration-config/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories

Comment: @spencergibb do you think it would be possible for an application to customize the BootstrapImportSelector in order to exclude specific BootstrapConfigurations, similarly to what the AutoConfigurationImportSelector does (either via env property exclusion or spring.factories filter injection)? That is, without resorting to bytecode manipulation or similar hacky ways. I'd love to hear some advice about how you'd achieve such customization!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [class you want to exclude](https://github.com/microsoft/spring-cloud-azure/blob/master/spring-cloud-azure-appconfiguration-config/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/spring/cloud/config/AppConfigurationBootstrapConfiguration.java#L34) you can set the following to disable it

```
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.enabled=false
```

Comment: Sadly this property is also tied to other configuration classes that must be parsed instead, therefore I cannot set it to false.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple in spring boot. If application your file location is "/src/main/resources/bootstrap.yml"  then it is automatically execute when your application start.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I do not need to inject a BootstrapConfiguration, rather exclude one. And the bootstrapping of that configuration is not directly under my control as the configuration along with the bootstrap is located in another project, that cannot be directly modified.